# Java ou C# para desenvolver um sistema de gestão agricola?

Tags: java, c#

Estou a fazer avaliação da linguagem que melhor se adapta para esse sistema agricola desktop

Comment: A conversa ficou longa e  foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132520/discussion-on-question-by-jorge-ndonga-java-ou-c-para-desenvolver-um-sistema-de), quem tive interesse em participar ou continuar, basta usar o link fornecido. Sobre o fechamento e para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site vale a pena ler O que é o Stack Overflow e o Guia de sobrevivência. É difícil fugir do opinativo, mas talvez editar a pergunta e dar mais parâmetros viabilize respostas.